# practice question about compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $(F_i)$ $i \in I$ be a family of nonempty closed subsets with empty intersection. Prove that there exists a positive $c$ such that for each $x \in X$, $d(x,F_i) \geqslant c$ for some $i \in I$.   $$$$ I worked on it for a while but I think it's too obvious. Use contraction is $\forall c$ $\exists x$ such that $d(x,F_i)<c$ for all $i \in I$, which means a point $x \in \operatorname{closure} F_i$ for all $i \in I$. That's impossible. We are learning compact set, I cannot use this condition... What's wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. If $F_i\not=\emptyset$ than theres always an $x\in F_i\subset X$ with $d(x,F_i)=0$ or is there is a definition I don't know?

Comment: ah now I get it, thx @Hagen von Eitzen

Answer (score 1):

The claim is $$\exists c>0\forall x\in X\exists i\in I\colon d(x,F_i)\ge c,$$ so the negation is $$\forall c>0\exists x\in X\forall i\in I\colon d(x,F_i)<c.$$ This does not entail that there is an $x$ in the closure of all $F_i$, which might be written as $$\exists x\in X\forall c>0\forall i\in I\colon d(x,F_i)<c.$$

---

Instead, note that the complements of the $F_i$ are open and their union covers $X$, then apply compactness.

Comment: Got it, thank you a lot!